# I'm not getting any output in the correct code (2nd code)?

Tags: python-3.x, format-string, title-case

Hi and thanks in advance for any help.

Here is the code that works with the proper output.

```
first_name="ada"
last_name="lovelace"
full_name=f"{first_name} {last_name}"
message=(f"Hello, {full_name.title()}!")
print(message)
```

Here is the similar code with no output...and I can't figure out why?

```
first_name="ada"
last_name="lovelace"
full_name=f"{first_name} {last_name}"
print(full_name)
```

I know it is correct coding based on the teacher's response but can't figure out why?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Both work fine for me on Python 3.6.5. How do you execute them?

Comment: Although both work as Selcuk suggested the second one is not capitalized due to missing `.title()` fucntion. See my answer for to possible methods to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add `.title()` to your string formatting request.

You can do either:

```py
# to get both capitalized add .title() twice here at "full name".

first_name="ada"
last_name="lovelace"
full_name=f"{first_name.title()} {last_name.title()}"   
print(full_name)
```

or:

```py
# to get both capitalized add .title() once here at "message".

first_name="ada"
last_name="lovelace"
full_name=f"{first_name} {last_name}"
message=(f"{full_name.title()}")
print(message)
```